# Why these bindings are not working as expected?

Tags: wpf, binding, menuitem, togglebutton

I have the following sample which mimics an application with a menu and a status bar button doing the same thing.

If I only execute the command from the menu the toolbar button gets updated fine but if I start using the toolbarbutton the menu and the toolbar gets out of synch. The same happens if I do the other way around starting with the toolbar button the menu gets updated until I use the menu for the fist time.

What I'm missing?

C#:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Picis.Wpf.Framework.Commands;

namespace CheckTest
{
public partial class Window1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _state;

    public ICommand ChangeStateCommand { get; private set; }

    public bool State
    {
        get
        {
            return _state;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_state != value)
            {
                _state = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("State");
            }
        }
    }

    public Window1()
    {
        this.ChangeStateCommand = new DelegateCommand<bool>(ExecuteChangeState);
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private void ExecuteChangeState(bool state)
    {
        this.State = !state;
    }
}
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CheckTest.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<StackPanel>
    <Menu IsMainMenu="True">
        <MenuItem IsChecked="{Binding State, Mode=OneWay}" Command="{Binding ChangeStateCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding State}" Header="Test" IsCheckable="True"  />
    </Menu>
    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding State, Mode=OneWay}" Command="{Binding ChangeStateCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding State}" Content="Test2" />
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: You bind `OneWay`, why? That way if you interact with the controls changes will not affect the bound property.

Comment: I want the bound property to be changed by the command. Ex: I start an engine with the button and I want the start button disabled after the engine say it's started, not after clicking the button. The IsChecked property should be only a confirmation.

Comment: In any case you should only use either mechanism: Command or IsChecked, and the binding should be TwoWay if you use IsChecked.

Comment: why should I avoid using IsChecked as a confirmation? In the end the IsChecked only modifies the visual representation of the button. I always thought on Command as the way to execute the order and IsChecked as the way to confirm it's execution not as a way of "hidding" a command on a property setter.

Comment: You can perfectly modify bools only with IsChecked if IsCheckable is true. What i meant was that you should not have that and true and use a Command at the same time. If your command only toggles a bool you don't need it, use IsCheckable and bind IsChecked TwoWay.

Comment: Oh, now I get you, thanks. This is just a sample, I'm starting a real engine that is connecting to several subsystems and doing real work and is perfectly possible that the operation does not complete at all. I'm executing a real command ... if all I had to do was to negate a bool ... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have imported your code into a new project. 
I had to import my implementation of Delegate command which is basically the non generic version of [relay command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) by Josh Smith and everything works fine (the two items remain synced no matter which order they are clicked).

The only update to the code I made was the following which basically accommodates the fact that my version of delegate command is non-generic.

```
private void ExecuteChangeState(object parameter)
{
    bool s = (bool)parameter;
    this.State = !s;
}
```

The xaml remains unchanged from your post (My understanding is that the Path parameter is implicit in the binding so it makes no difference if it is specified or not).

I'm suspecting the issue could be that there is something wrong with the implementation of DelegateCommand you are working with. Alternatively, the sample you posted might be missing something from your actual application that is giving you the problem.

Are you certain the code you have posted adequately models the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: I found that on VS2010 with .Net 4 it's working as expected. I initially did my tests on VS2008 with .Net 3.5 ... :?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `CommandParameter="{Binding State}"` from your `MenuItem` and `ToggleButton`.

Then, change your `ExecuteChangeState` to switch itself on itself, rather than a passed in parameter:

```
private void ExecuteChangeState()
{
    this.State = !_state;
}
```

That will ensure that the switch always switches on the current value of State, and that the front-end of your application is always in sync with the variable values of State.

Comment: `{Binding State} == {Binding Path=State}`